# How to host more than 3 domains on amazon lightsail?

Tags: amazon-lightsail

Amazon lightsail currently supports creation of 3 DNS zones. My question is how can i host more than 3 domains under same account as it wont let me create the 4th DNS zone for 4th domain name that i want to host. Can anyone help here ?

Tried to create a new DNS zone so i could update the nameservers but it failed as limits have reached.

Answer (score 1):

Three zones is the limit currently ... if you need more, they will probably tell you to use Route53.

Alternatively, you could use a different domain registrar that offers free DNS services (like Google Domains).